# Проблема с точностью float

Tags: c#, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Есть такой код:

```
Debug.Log((p > 10));
```

В переменной p тоже число 10.

Я запускаю 100 итераций данного кода.

Получилось:
90 Сообщений False и 10 Сообщений True

Должно быть все сообщения False.

Чтобы подобного не происходило, для оператора == используют Mathf.Approximately. А как быть с операторами > и <? Я пробовал вот так, но это не помогло:

```
Debug.Log((p > 10 + Mathf.Epsilon));
```

Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Либо вы что то не договариваете, либо у вас в 10 случаях из 100 `p` больше 10. Приведите рабочий пример где данная проблема проявляется.

Comment: Debug.Log((p  - 10 >  Mathf.Epsilon));

Comment: `Math.Round` еще может помочь. И я бы использовал `double` для вычислений вместо `float`.

Comment: А я бы использовал decimal чтоб не заморачиваться вообще

Comment: @aepot, В Unity используется float для всех вычислениях

Comment: @AimonZ. еслиб вы проеряли на равенство какойто константы то я б понял в чем проблема. У вас же неравенство и мне удивительно что неравенство даёт неверный результат в 10 из 100 случаев. Привидите примеры у которых это неверно по вашему мнению

Comment: выражение "В переменной p тоже число 10." нужно читать так - "значение p вычисляется моими функциями, судя по выводу, оно должно быть близко к 10. просто иногда там 9.9999999, а иногда 10.00000001. Так как вывод очень часто идет по 6 цифр после запятой, то оба числа выглядят как 10"

Comment: @KoVadim, может ответом?

Comment: @KoVadim в такм случае `Math.Round()` наверное должно помочь.

Comment: возможно. мы не знаем, насколько там все плохо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Получилось долго, но надеюсь интересно. А то писать ответы в две строки уже надоело:)

## Старая история

Когда я учился в ВУЗе, у нас была большая расчётная задача, которая рассчитывалась двумя способами. А в конце два ответа должны были сойтись. Преподаватель допускал расхождение в 20%. Но проблема в том, что одна ветка вычислений - это около пол сотни только умножений. А ещё там была тригонометрия и логарифмы. И сам расчет занимал около часа, при условии, что человек понимает, что он делает.

И анализ расчетов не показывал ошибку. Если такой же расчет делал сосед, то у него получалась своя пара чисел. Когда у меня было 3 пары чисел, я понял, что так дело не пойдет.

### математики раскрывают глаза

Но потом выяснилась причина - делая расчёты на калькуляторе, почти всегда на автомате округлял до 2-3 цифр после запятой (лень же 10-12 цифр переписывать). Преподаватель по математике, посмотрев на это, сказал, что легко получить разброс в полтора-два раза (что собственно и наблюдалось).

Поэтому, я вооружился Delfi и написал свой расчет. И в конце сошлось с точностью в сотые процента. Сравнивая с моими ручными расчетами, обнаружилось, что ошибка постепенно накапливалась. Но вот преподаватель, которая принимала работу, была немного в шоке (она не видела, что бы так сходились цифры и с калькулятором пыталась найти, где же именно я "подогнал").

### физики также в курсе

Поэтому, когда на физике (к примеру, на лабораторной работе или докторской диссертации) пишутся результаты расчетов, без указания погрешности они "не имеют никакого физического смысла".

Потом я сделал ещё расчет с расчетом погрешности на каждом шаге и все сошлось, но об этом ниже.

## Теперь ближе к вопросу.

Посмотрим на такие варианты получения числа 10 (да, этот код на плюсах, но это ничего не меняет)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

void print(float f)
{
    std::cout
    // точность вывода по умолчанию
    << std::setprecision(6) << f << " = "
    // максимальная точность вывода
    << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1)
    << f << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    float f1 = 10.0;
    print(f1);
    //
    float f2 = 1.0 / 3.0 * 30;
    print(f2);
    //
    float f3 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { f3+=0.1;}
    print(f3);
    //
    float f4 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { f4+=0.01;}
    print(f4);
     //
     float f5 = exp(log(2)+log(5));
     print(f5);
}
```

вывод

> 10 = 10
> 10 = 10
> 10 = 10.00000190734863281
> 10.0001 = 10.00013351440429688
> 10 = 10

Хотя эти все способы и дают 10, но это все немного "разные 10". В втором и пятом случае компилятор оптимизировал и там "честная 10.0" (да, компиляторы они такие. Иногда могут творить чудеса и скрывать пользовательские ошибки.

Теперь нужно понять, что оператор == для двух вещественных чисел делает просто побитовое сравнение (если типы не совпадают, то их вначале нужно "подогнать", а это ещё дополнительные ошибки).

Также, сразу видно, что в четвертом случае при выводе похоже что там 10, но по факту нет.

### как же такое могло произойти?

Теперь пойдем ещё ближе. В своем коде похоже Вы делаете какие то расчеты, которые должны давать идентичные результаты. Но получаете их немного по разному (к примеру, это могут быть расчеты площади фигуры [методом Монте-Карло](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE)).

### игры также в курсе

В играх бывает похожий случай. Допустим у нас есть бродилка и главный герой может перемещается только шагами определенного размера. Естественно, к его текущим координатам мы добавляем/вычитаем размер шага. И ходя по комнате и вернувшись на начальную точку, можем обнаружить, что мы немного сместились. Это иногда бывает "очень неожиданным". В тех же шуттерах пуля может пролететь "рядом", хотя мы и целились очень точно.

## Ищем решение

Что же делать? Нужно учитывать вот ту погрешность результатов. Иногда предлагают использовать ту же `EPS`, но это не совсем верный способ. Нужно сравнить два результата не как точечный результаты, а как два отрезка.

### простые сложные примеры

Давайте посмотрим на такие сравнения 10±3 и 9±2. Если перевести их в "отрезки", это будет [7;13] и [7;11]. Скорее всего большинство людей будет считать первое больше второго. Но, учитывая погрешность, они могут быть равными. А могут и не быть. Поэтому, правильный ответ: 10±3 ≊ 9±2 (это знак равно или почти равно)

Новый вариант 10±3 и 5±2 -> [7;13] и [3;7]. И хотя на первый взгляд кажется, что второе число однозначно меньше, но это не так. При определенных обстоятельствах они могут быть равны 7. Да, вероятность этого достаточно низкая, но все же она существует. Поэтому здесь правильный знак 10±3 ≥ 5±2, как бы это и не было странно.

Но многие об этом забывают. А потом получаются странные результаты... А потом вдруг, "а есть ли о погрешности погрешность?"

### как быть?

Как же сравнивать, учитывая все это? А тут всегда нужно смотреть на целевую задачу. Если это к примеру координаты человечка на карте, то лучше координаты округлять до кратности шага или вообще хранить в целых числах. Если это координаты корабля, то двойной размер корабля будет хороших мерилом точности. Если это расчет атомной бомбы, то тут похоже ошиблись форумом.

### подбираемся к решению

Перейдем к коду. Я бы делал так сравнение на больше

```
abs(a-b) > eps && a>b
```

что в принципе можно переписать и как

```
a > b + eps
```

где eps либо выбирается методом "тыка" с подходящего справочника, либо просто сумма погрешности измерения для двух переменных.

### а это уже формально ответ на вопрос

Посмотрим, что с Вашим способом сравнения не так

```
Debug.Log((p > 10 + Mathf.Epsilon));
```

выглядит он как мой. Но если посмотреть, что такое [Mathf.Epsilon](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.double.epsilon?view=netcore-3.1), то оказывается это

> Представляет наименьшее положительное значение Double больше нуля. Это поле является константой.

Скажем так, это "атомарное" (то есть, неделимое, минимальное) положительное число. Разделить попалам его уже нельзя. Если немного подумать, то станет очевидно, что сравнение с ним немного бессмысленно - уж слишком маленькое это число

```
public const double Epsilon = 4.94065645841247E-324;
```

В любом случае, по ссылке выше об этом же и написано

> При создании пользовательского алгоритма, который определяет, считаются ли два числа с плавающей запятой равными, мы не рекомендуем основывать свой алгоритм на значении Epsilon константы, чтобы добиться приемлемого абсолютного поля разности для двух значений, которые будут считаться равными

(это какой то машинный перевод, но вроде понятно).

## P.S.

Оставлю эту игрушку здесь https://evanw.github.io/float-toy/ - очень помогает понять, как там все внутри крутится.